# Proving the correctness of a sorting algorithm that contains a whole loop

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof

I am preparing for my algorithm and data structures exam. In the code below, I need to prove the correctness of tripSort for arrays of a size >=3. I am trying to do that by using loop invariants. The subarray A[n-2j+1,n] is the loop invariant I chose, where j refers to the iterations of the while loop. Is this the correct way to prove the correctness?

```
 public static boolean threeSort(int[] arr) {
    boolean changed = false;
    if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
        swap(arr, 0, 1);
        changed = true;
    }
    if (arr[0] > arr[2]) {
        swap(arr, 0, 2);
        changed = true;
    }
    if (arr[1] > arr[2]) {
        swap(arr, 1, 2);
        changed = true;
    }
    return changed;
}

public static void tripSort(int[] A) {
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        done = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length - 2; i++) {
            if (threeSort(new int[]{A[i], A[i + 1], A[i + 2]})) {
                done = false; // something changed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input has at least length 3, you can do it in two steps:

1. Prove the outer loop terminates. You can do this by an argument that the total number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) is always non-negative, and strictly decreasing in each iteration where `done = false`, and thus the loop must terminate.
2. Prove that when the outer loop terminates, the array is sorted. You can do this with a loop invariant that while `done = true`, after the `i`th iteration you have $a[0] \leq \cdots \leq a[i+1] \leq a[i+2]$.

Answer (score 0):

You can not prove this sorting algorithm as correct because it is not correct. Hint: what happens if the input contains two elements?

Comment: i forgot to mention that the correctness needs to be proved for arrays with a size greater than or equal to 3 @orlp